# Ordering a catalog/product collection by sales data

Tags: collection, magento-1.6

I have a 'catalog/product' collection which is being filtered by product attributes, but I need to order this collection so that the most popular (sales OR views) come first.

Is there a way to do this?

This is my code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('recipient', 13)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('personality', 99)

$collection->clear()->setPageSize(10)->load();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try below code to have most popular (View count) collection

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->addViewsCount()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('recipient', 13)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('personality', 99);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `->addOrderedQty()` to you collection and then set an order `->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel(‘reports/product_collection’)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('recipient', 13)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('personality', 99)
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->order('ordered_qty DESC');
```